# AWS Elasticsearch Avg aggregation Java API generates error while trying to retrieve results using Jest client during a certain time period

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using Elasticsearch SDK 2.3 and also Jest 2.0.0 to create a client. I am trying to get average aggregation (and other aggregations) implemented which will retrieve results from a certain time period.

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    //Queries builder
    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());

    GregorianCalendar gC = new GregorianCalendar();
    gC.set(2016, Calendar.OCTOBER, 18, 0, 0, 0);
    long from = gC.getTimeInMillis();
    gC.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    long to = gC.getTimeInMillis();

    searchSourceBuilder.postFilter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("timestamp").from(from).to(to));

    JestClient client = getJestClient();

    AvgBuilder aggregation2 = AggregationBuilders
            .avg(AvgAggregation.TYPE)
            .field("backend_processing_time");


    AggregationBuilder ag = AggregationBuilders.dateRange(aggregation2.getName())
            .addRange("timestamp", from, to).
            subAggregation(aggregation2);

    searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(ag);
    String query = searchSourceBuilder.toString();
    Search search = new Search.Builder(query)
            .addIndex(INDEX)
            .addType(TYPE)
            //                .addSort(new Sort("code"))
            .setParameter(Parameters.SIZE, 5)
            //                .setParameter(Parameters.SCROLL, "5m")
            .build();

    SearchResult result = client.execute(search);
    System.out.println("ES Response with aggregation:\n" + result.getJsonString());
```

And the error that I am getting is the following:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"aggregation_execution_exception","reason":"could not find the appropriate value context to perform aggregation [avg]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"elbaccesslogs_2016_10","node":"5ttEmYcTTsie-z23OpKY0A","reason":{"type":"aggregation_execution_exception","reason":"could not find the appropriate value context to perform aggregation [avg]"}}]},"status":500}

Looks like the reason is 'could not find the appropriate value context to perform aggregation [avg]' ... which I don't know really what is going on.

Can anyone suggest anything please? Or if need more info on this before responding, please let me know.

Thanks,

Khurram

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution myself so I am explaining below and closing the issue which is as follows:

Basically the code

```
searchSourceBuilder.postFilter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("timestamp").from(from).to(to));
```

doesn't work with aggregations. We need to remove 'postFilter' code and the following code:

```
AggregationBuilder ag = AggregationBuilders.dateRange(aggregation2.getName())
    .addRange("timestamp", from, to).
    subAggregation(aggregation2);
```

And change the following code too:

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
```

to

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery().
                    must(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()).
                    filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("timestamp").from(from).to(to))
    );
```

So here is the entire code again:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    GregorianCalendar gC = new GregorianCalendar();
    gC.set(2016, Calendar.OCTOBER, 18, 0, 0, 0);
    long from = gC.getTimeInMillis();
    gC.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    long to = gC.getTimeInMillis();

    searchSourceBuilder.query(
            QueryBuilders.boolQuery().
                    must(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()).
                    filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("timestamp").from(from).to(to))
    );

    JestClient client = getJestClient(); // just a private method creating a client the way Jest client is created

    AvgBuilder avg_agg = AggregationBuilders
            .avg(AvgAggregation.TYPE)
            .field("backend_processing_time");

    searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(avg_agg);

    String query = searchSourceBuilder.toString();

    Search search = new Search.Builder(query)
            .addIndex(INDEX)
            .addType(TYPE)
            .setParameter(Parameters.SIZE, 10)
            .build();

    SearchResult result = client.execute(search);
    System.out.println("ES Response with aggregation:\n" + result.getJsonString());
```